# Unexpected behavior for ternary operator in C++

Tags: c++

The C++ code shown below uses the **ternary operator** (**?**) and assigns an object of type GAME (**game**) to an integer variable (**g**).

Questions:

1. why it does not throw a compilation error (both types are clearly different) ?
2. why is its logical operation evaluated **true** ?
3. why is this logical operation evaluated **false** when the object game is instantiated not dynamically ? I mean when you comment out the line: 
   game = new GAME;

```c++
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class GAME
{  
public:
    int CurGame ();
};

int GAME::CurGame ()  {   return 100; }

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{    
    int g;
    GAME* game;

    game = new GAME;

    g = game ? 0 : game->CurGame();    

    printf("g: %d", g);   

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't "assign an object of type `GAME` to an integer variable". It assigns either `0` or the result of `GAME::CurGame` which is clearly an `int`.

Comment: Your ternary expression is the wrong way round

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. why it does not throw a compilation error (both types are clearly different) ?

No, the operands to the ternary operator are the same types. Specifically, both are of type `int`. You have an integer literal, `0`, which is of type `int`, and you have the result of the `CurGame` member function, which is of type `int`.

> 2. why is its logical operation evaluated true ?

In C++, you can think of the comparison against zero (the `!= 0` part of the expression) as being implicit. So when you do:

```
g = game ? 0 : game->CurGame();
```

this is equivalent to:

```
g = (game != 0) ? 0 : game->CurGame();
```

but, as a matter of idiom, you don't write it that way.

In words, all this does is set `g` equal to `0` if the `game` pointer is non-null, or set `g` equal to the current game otherwise.

…Which means that the conditional expression is backwards. You want `g` to be `0` if the `game` pointer is null, so you should write:

```
g = game ? game->CurGame() : 0;
```

> 3. why is this logical operation evaluated false when the object game is instantiated not dynamically ? I mean when you comment out the line: game = new GAME;

In this case, you have undefined behavior. When `game` is not initialized, attempting to read from it is undefined behavior. That means anything can happen: your program could work correctly, not at all, or your computer could explode.

In practice, what happens is that `game` contains garbage value leftover in memory, which is almost certainly non-zero.

This is one of the many reasons why you should prefer to *initialize* variables at the point of their declaration. So your code should really be rewritten as:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{    
    GAME* game = new GAME;

    int g = game ? game->CurGame() : 0;    

    printf("g: %d", g);   

    return 0; 
}
```

Notice that there's actually *less* code needed when you write it that way, which makes it easier to read, and therefore less likely to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> why it does not throw a compilation error (both types are clearly
>   different) ?

- No, they are both `int`, but there is one exception for ternary operators, where can be different types. And its for pointers. Its possible to use `void*` (`NULL`) as second or third operand.

> a ? b : c
>
> Expressions b and c must be compatible. That is, they must both be
>
> - arithmetic types
> - compatible struct or union types pointers to
>     compatible types (one of which might be the `nullptr`)
> - Alternatively, one operand is a pointer and the other is a `void*`
>     pointer.

- Because game has assigned memory from `new` operator and it means it doesn't point to `nullptr`
- Because `game` points to `nullptr`. Hasn't assigned dynamical memory.

Comment: As the tagging of this question changed from C/C++ to C++ only: Are you sure this "*Its possible to use void* (NULL) as second or third operand.*" hold for C++?

Comment: @alk You really dont like me right? Heh. Ok ill adapt my answer.

Comment: If not explicitly mentioned else (which happens very rarely), my comments/votes are ever and always *only* related to answers & questions, never to people. Still, you are active and I am active that's probably the reason we "bump" ... ;-)

Comment: @alk It was just joke, never mind :P Comments should be used for conversation, so thank you for your completing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The C++ code shown below uses the ternary operator (?) and assigns an object of type GAME (game) to an integer variable (g).

No, it does not. It assigns an `int`; either `0`, or `game->CurGame()`.

> 1. why it does not throw a compilation error (both types are clearly different) ?

There is an error in your premise. Both expressions `0` and `game->CurGame()` are of type `int`.

> 2. why is its logical operation evaluated true ?

Because the pointer does not point to null.

> 3. why is this logical operation evaluated false when the object game is instantiated not dynamically ? I mean when you comment out the line: game = new GAME;

If you comment out that line, the pointer will be uninitialized. Accessing the value of an uninitialized object has undefined behaviour.

---

`game->CurGame()` is only ever going to be called when `game` is null, in which case that invocation has undefined behaviour, because `game` is null.